# Mocked DbSet method throws NotImplementedException when called inside of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, moq, xunit.net

I have the following setup:

**DbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Album> Album { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class AlbumController : Controller
{

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public AlbumController(ApplicationDbContext injectDb)
    {
        db = injectDb;
    }

    // POST: Albums/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Album album = db.Album.Find(id);

        db.Album.Remove(album);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I wrote the unit test using Moq and xUnit to check DeleteConfirmed functionality:

```
 public class AlbumsControllerTests
    {
        public static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockDbSet<T>(List<T> inputDbSetContent) where T : class
        {
            var DbSetContent = inputDbSetContent.AsQueryable();
            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(DbSetContent.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(DbSetContent.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(DbSetContent.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => inputDbSetContent.GetEnumerator());
            dbSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => inputDbSetContent.Add(s));
            dbSet.Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => inputDbSetContent.Remove(s));
            return dbSet;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void DeleteConfirmedTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockAlbumSet = MockDbSet(new List<Album> { });

            Mock<ApplicationDbContext> sutDbContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>() { CallBase = true };
            sutDbContext.Setup(m => m.Album).Returns(mockAlbumSet.Object);

            // Check if Album.Remove works inside this test
            var albumToBeDeleted = new Album() { AlbumID = 1, Title = "TestAlbumName" };

            sutDbContext.Object.Album.Add(albumToBeDeleted);
            Assert.Equal(1, (from a in sutDbContext.Object.Album select a).Count());

            sutDbContext.Object.Album.Remove(albumToBeDeleted);
            Assert.Equal(0, (from a in sutDbContext.Object.Album select a).Count());

            // Actual Test
            sutDbContext.Object.Album.Add(albumToBeDeleted);
            sutDbContext.Setup(m => m.Album.Find(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(albumToBeDeleted);

            AlbumController sut = new AlbumController(sutDbContext.Object);

            var output = sut.DeleteConfirmed(1); // Throws NotImplementedException

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(0, (from a in sutDbContext.Object.Album select a).Count());
        }
    }
```

The test throws the following exception on **db.Album.Remove(album)** in **DeleteConfirmed**:

> **System.NotImplementedException** : The member 'Remove' has not been
>   implemented on type 'DbSet`1Proxy' which inherits from 'DbSet`1'. Test
>   doubles for 'DbSet`1' must provide implementations of methods and
>   properties that are used.

As you can see in MockDbSet method body, I setup Remove method for my Mock and **it works just fine inside the unit test**. Can you explain me why it doesn't work inside the controller?

Comment: You seem to inject some DbContext implementation to your controller, can you add code that shows which one?

Comment: @raderick I inject ApplicationDbContext mock (you can check its source code on the top). Initialization is in the test: AlbumController(sutDbContext.Object). It's the same DbContext I used in test body.

Comment: Test code looks weird overall, in lines after `// Check if Album.Remove works inside this test` you test your mock setups, which is incorrect. Your `sut.DeleteConfirmed` also partially tests your Mock setups. I would advise you to switch your DbSet<Album> to IDbSet<Album> and use `dbSetMock.Verify(x=>x.Remove(albumToBeDeleted))` to test that code is called without testing any implementation details

Comment: Your controller should depend on abstractions and not on concretions. would make dependencies easier to change/mock

Comment: @raderick It's not an actual test, just a quick demonstration of the issue to show that same functionality works in the test and doesn't work inside of controller. I understand that your advice is the best way to test controllers where all business logic is in model Unfortunately, it's not always the case, and it doesn't explain the behaviour I showed (that's the whole point).

Comment: @Nkosi Could you elaborate on that? I didn't add any DbContext interface to the example for the sake of transparency, if that's what you're pointing out.

Comment: Caribou, @raderick's answer is correct. the last setup wins when configuring moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test will work fine if you change your line:

```
sutDbContext.Setup(m => m.Album.Find(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(albumToBeDeleted);
```

To:

```
mockAlbumSet.Setup(x=>x.Find(It.IsAny<int>()))
           .Returns(albumToBeDeleted);
```

You made a setup for your sutDbContext to return `mockAlbumSet.Object` when `sutDbContext.Album` is called, but that line overridden your setup to create a new mock object for `sutDbContext.Album` property and created a single setup for that mock:

```
m.Album.Find(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(albumToBeDeleted);
```

Here is a simple test, that shows you that calling setup for nested property of the class, that was previously setup to return a Mock.Object, will override that property with a new Mock.Object:

```
public interface IParentService
{
    IDependantService Dependant { get; }
}

public interface IDependantService
{
    void Execute();
}

[Fact]
//This test passes
public void VerifyThatNestedMockSetupGeneratesNewMockObject()
{
    var value = 0;  

    var parentServiceMock = new Mock<IParentService>();
    var dependantServiceMock = new Mock<IDependantService>();
    dependantServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Execute()).Callback(() => { value = 1; });

    parentServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Dependant).Returns(dependantServiceMock.Object);

    Assert.Same(parentServiceMock.Object.Dependant, dependantServiceMock.Object);
    parentServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Dependant.Execute()).Callback(() => { value = 2; });
    Assert.NotSame(parentServiceMock.Object.Dependant, dependantServiceMock.Object);

    parentServiceMock.Object.Dependant.Execute();

    Assert.Equal(2, value);
}
```